# Integer trace and norm $\Rightarrow$ integral element in $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[3]{d}\bigr)$?

Tags: number-theory

Does an algebraic number field $\mathbb{Q}\bigl(\sqrt[3]{d}\bigr)$ with $d$ cube-free exist, which contains a non-integral element $\alpha$ with integer trace and integer norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1-\root3\of{28})/3$ seems to work.